# FastAPI Update Operation with SQLAlchemy ORM and Pydantic Model: 'TypeError: Query.update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I've implemented a FastAPI method to update a record in my application. First, I check if the todo record exists, and then I attempt to update it. However, I'm encountering the following error: "TypeError: Query.update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'."

Here's a simplified version of the code where the error occurs:

```
@app.put('/todos/{id}', status_code=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED, response_model=TodoResponse)
def update(id: int, request: TodoRequest, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    todo = db.query(models.Todo).filter(models.Todo.id == id)
    if not todo.first():
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f"todo with id {id} not found.")

    todo.update(title=request.title, completed=request.completed)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(todo)
    return todo
```

I've also tried using todo.update(request), but that didn't work either.

Can you please provide guidance on how to correctly update the record using SQLAlchemy ORM and Pydantic models in FastAPI? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`todo` is a `Query` item of sqlalchemy. The `update` function takes in a dictionary.

```py
update = dict(title=request.title, completed=request.completed)
todo.update(update)
```